# Laravel: Prevent Illuminate\Support\Arr::dot() from creating keys for one-dimension array items

Tags: laravel

When converting an array to dot notation with `Illuminate\Support\Arr::dot()` like this:

```
$foo = [
  "bar" => [
    "name" => "Bob",
    "age" => 60,
    "colors" => ["red", "green", "blue"]
  ]
];
Arr::dot($foo);
```

I'm getting:

```
[
  "bar.name" => "Bob",
  "bar.age" => 60,
  "bar.colors.0" => "red",
  "bar.colors.1" => "blue",
  "bar.colors.2" => "green",
]
```

How can I get this instead ?

```
[
  "bar.name" => "Bob",
  "bar.age" => 60,
  "bar.colors" => ["red", "green", "blue"]
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$foo = [
  "bar" => [
    "name" => "Bob",
    "age" => 60,
    "colors" => ["red", "green", "blue"]
  ]
];

$temp = data_get($foo, 'bar.colors');

unset($foo['bar']['colors']);

$result = Arr::dot($foo) + ['colors' => $temp];
```